# How to remove autocompleted fields' default style in iOS's version of Chrome browser

Tags: css

I succeeded in fakely removing the styles of autocompleted fields in most of the browsers and to keep the transparent background with the CSS code below. I read [the CSS tricks' article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/). It works with Chrome for Android and Safari for iOS but unfortunatly not with the iOS's version of Chrome.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  transition: all 0s 50000s;
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you this: [CLICK HERE](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/)

You can find your answer there! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already read this article and apply its recommandations but it doesn't work for the iOS's version of Chrome.